# COMO TRATAR VALORES VAZIOS EM VARIAS COLUNAS?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query

Tenho uma TB que possui 15 colunas de telefone, onde varias linhas estão vazias. Preciso transformar essas 15 colunas em somente uma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o UNION ALL e colocando uma condição no WHERE para me livrar dos valores vazios, consegui resolver grande parte do meu problema só que tenho que executar a query abaixo mais 14 vezes para poder subir no banco de produção.

```
SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO), 
   TRIM(NOME), 
   TRIM(CPF),
   RTRIM(TELEFONE),
   RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM cob_clr  
WHERE TELEFONE <> '';
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe outra maneira de tratar esses valores VAZIOS em uma única consulta sem precisar repetir a query acima mais 14 vezes de modo que fique como no print abaixo ?

Obg!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *"possui 15 colunas de telefone"* nossa que modelagem é essa? deveria ter uma única coluna e inserir por demanda se precisar de 1 insere 1, se precisa de 5 insere 5 e assim por diante. Está tentando resolver um problema de modelagem na query, o que é bem ruim. Sobre a query, não importa se vai fazer join ou union ou outro artifício, vai ter de fazer 15 vezes, o melhor seria filtrar isso, por numa tabela a parte com os dados que precisa e listar isso, como deveria ser essa modelagem, mas para isso precisaria usar uma *procedure*

Comment: Obg pelo retorno Ricardo, concordo com você sobre essa modelagem mas infelizmente é dessa forma que recebo do cliente e como eles não querem alterar preciso fazer o tratamento do meu lado para utilização.

Comment: explica melhor uma coisa, imagina que a linha tem os telefones 1 a 3 preenchidos e o resto null, qual vai retornar entre eles? o primeiro? isso não entendi bem

Comment: Isso meio que seria irrelevante. Caso eu tenha somente esses três telefones iria tentam contato com os três até ter o retorno positivo de algum deles indicando que esse número X é o de contato atual do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Posto que o modelo é este:

Faça uma view do tipo

```
CREATE VIEW OR REPLACE VIEW 
V_CLIENTE AS

SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO) AS OPERACAO, 
       TRIM(NOME) AS NOME, 
       TRIM(CPF) AS CPF,
       RTRIM(TELEFONE) AS TELEFONE,
       RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM TABELA
WHERE RTRIM(TELEFONE) IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO) AS OPERACAO, 
       TRIM(NOME) AS NOME, 
       TRIM(CPF) AS CPF,
       RTRIM(TELEFONE_2) AS TELEFONE,
       RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM TABELA
WHERE RTRIM(TELEFONE_2) IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO) AS OPERACAO, 
       TRIM(NOME) AS NOME, 
       TRIM(CPF) AS CPF,
       RTRIM(TELEFONE_3) AS TELEFONE,
       RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM TABELA
WHERE RTRIM(TELEFONE_3) IS NOT NULL
UNION all
... repete de 3 até 15
```

Não testado evidentemente , apenas uma ideia pelo que entendi do problema.

Comment: Obg pelo retorno Motta, vou pesquisar mais sobre esse método.

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar aqui como resolvi esse problema, talvez isso ajude alguém futuramente.

Lembrando que o que eu fiz aqui não e recomendado mas foi a maneira que consegui para resolver esse problema até a integração de um novo CRM.

**Os principais problemas eram unir todas as 15 colunas de telefones e retirar os espaços em branco.**

Segue solução...

#1 - Carreguei toda a base recebida com 32 colunas(arquivo puro).

#2 - Aqui que começa o tratamento, não preciso utilizar todas as colunas do arquivo carregado então utilizando a ideia do Motta, criei uma View e repeti a consulta até a coluna TELEFONE_15, conforme abaixo.

```
CREATE VIEW OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_CLIENTE AS

SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO) AS OPERACAO, 
       TRIM(NOME) AS NOME, 
       TRIM(CPF) AS CPF,
       RTRIM(TELEFONE) AS TELEFONE,
       RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM TABELA
WHERE RTRIM(TELEFONE) IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(OPERACAO) AS OPERACAO, 
       TRIM(NOME) AS NOME, 
       TRIM(CPF) AS CPF,
       RTRIM(TELEFONE_2) AS TELEFONE,
       RTRIM(substring(SAL_AB_ATR_CL_AG,19,9)) as ATR
FROM TABELA
WHERE RTRIM(TELEFONE_2) IS NOT NULL
```

#3 -Depois que a VIEW foi criada rodo um CASE  para saber o que é Fixo ou Móvel, assim as pessoas que vão utilizar a base futuramente conseguem ter uma visão melhor do que priorizar...

```
SELECT  operacao, nome, cpf, telefone,
CASE
WHEN LENGTH(tel1) = 10  THEN  'Fixo'
WHEN LENGTH(tel1) = 11  THEN  'Celular'
ELSE  'erro' END
FROM VIEW_CLIENTE LIMIT 10;
```

#4 - Depois disso exporto o resultado e importo no banco de produção é fim do problema.

Novamente, lembrando que essa solução que fiz creio eu que não seja recomenda mas como eu recebo a base do cliente dessa maneira tenho que dar meu jeito de trabalhar...

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Saudações. eu tenho um problema similar, contudo este envolve uma coluna json. Eu extraio algumas informações deste modo:

```
CASE WHEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[60].title") = 'Banco'
THEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[60].value")  
END AS 'Banco 001',

CASE WHEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[66].title") = 'Banco'
THEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[66].value")  
END AS 'Banco 002',
    
CASE WHEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[67].title") = 'Banco'
THEN json_extract(clients.customFields, "$[67].value")  
END AS 'Banco 003'
```

Com isso, eu gero três colunas com as informações que, dependendo do registro, pode ou não conter informações. Como eu poderia unir essas 3 colunas em uma única, baseado no critério de desconsiderar a vazia (ou considerar a primeira que contém dados)?

Grato!